# Subscription center where we can update our profile I want to add multi-select checkbox

Tags: marketing-cloud, subscription-center

[image]

I want to add the multi-picklist field on the update profile page which will be mapped to the salesforce field and will update the selected values in the respective fields on the lead or contact object can anyone help tell me if is there any way to do this

Answer (score 2):

Profile Attributes cannot be mapped to Lookup Relationships, Checkboxes, or Picklists (Multi-Select)

Source: https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000386704&language=es&type=1